# ¿Cómo crear un archivo en una carpeta especifica que salga a partir de un resultado de un SP? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, csv

Muy buenas gente, como bien dice el titulo de la pregunta...

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de crear un archivo en una carpeta compartida que yo quiera especificar al momento de ejecutar un SP en SQL Server.

Pasa que tengo un reporte que actualmente envió por correo de forma diaria y el tamaño supera el limite permitido, llegando a exceder hasta los 50 mb por lo que la cantidad de datos es bastante y esto lo saco de la DB y lo adjunto como un csv por medio del mismo SP y se envía por correo electrónico.

Cabe recalcar que la DB que manejo esta alojada en un servidor de la empresa, por eso el tema de la carpeta compartida.

Ejemplo:

```
select @f_query_list = 'select 
      CARTERA,
      POLIZA,
      [FECHA LLENADO DJS],
      [NUMERO DE OPERACION],
      [No. SOLICITUD],
      ASEGURADO,
      GENERO,
      [CEDULA DE IDENTIDAD],
      EX,
      [FECHA DE NACIMIENTO],
      EDAD,
      [MONTO SOLICITADO EN USD],
      [RESPUESTAS AFIRMATIVAS],
      [ACLARACION RESPUESTAS AFIRMATIVAS],
      [% DE EXTRA PRIMA],
      [MOTIVO EXTRA PRIMA],
      [MOTIVO EXCLUSION],
      [COBERTURA OTORGADA],
      [FECHA DE PRONUNCIAMIENTO],
      COBERTURA
    from ##SUSCRIPTIONUPLOADDELIVERTEMP
    order by CARTERA desc, ESTADO asc'
```

Una vez que tengo listado mi resultado, lo adjunto en mi envio de correo electronico en formato csv y separado por puntos y comas "**;**"

```
select @f_name_archive_list='RSP-SUSCRIPCIÓN-DH-' + CAST(@f_fecha_inicio_dia AS VARCHAR(11)) + '.csv'
     set @f_asunto='Reporte de Suscripción (DH) ' +CAST(FORMAT(@f_fecha_inicio_dia,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS varchar(20))
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'SG',
        @recipients = @f_mail_to,
        --@copy_recipients = @f_mail_cc,
        @blind_copy_recipients=@f_mail_cc,
        @body= @f_body,
        @query=@f_query_list,
        @subject=@f_asunto,
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_attachment_filename=@f_name_archive_list,
        @execute_query_database = @f_base,
        @query_result_header     = 1,
        @query_result_width          = 32767,
        @query_result_separator=@f_separador
```

Así como lo tengo actualmente funciona hasta llegar al limite de tamaño permitido como adjuntos del servidor de correos y lo que se busca es que se cree en una dirección especifica como se explico mas arriba y adjuntar la url donde se encuentra alojado el documento.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido. Creo que a tu pregunta le vendría bien un [mcve], sin él, es difícil entender dónde estás teniendo la dificultad que mencionas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teóricamente, no se puede hacer directamente desde un SP. Sin embargo, podemos hacer un llamado a un procedimiento extendido que tiene SQL Server para llamar a la utilería bcp. bcp es una utilería que nos permite importar y exportar archivos de texto hacia/desde la base de datos.

El formato base quedaría como

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerarArchivo
AS
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(4000),
        @columnas nvarchar(4000),
        @query    nvarchar(4000);

-- Hacemos una cadena con todas las columnas y nos aseguramos de que sea una sola linea
SET @columnas = 'CARTERA,POLIZA,[FECHA LLENADO DJS],[NUMERO DE OPERACION],[No. SOLICITUD],ASEGURADO,GENERO,'
              + '[CEDULA DE IDENTIDAD],EX,[FECHA DE NACIMIENTO],EDAD,[MONTO SOLICITADO EN USD],[RESPUESTAS AFIRMATIVAS],'
              + '[ACLARACION RESPUESTAS AFIRMATIVAS],[% DE EXTRA PRIMA],[MOTIVO EXTRA PRIMA],[MOTIVO EXCLUSION],'
              + '[COBERTURA OTORGADA],[FECHA DE PRONUNCIAMIENTO],COBERTURA';
          
              -- Solo incluimos el cabecero en la primer linea
select @query = 'select CASE row_number() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) WHEN 1 THEN ' 
              -- Reemplazamos las comas por punto y coma, quitamos los corchetes y cambiamos de linea al final del cabecero
              + REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( @columnas, ',', ';'), '[', ''), ']', '') + ' + char(13) + char(10) ELSE '''' END, ' 
              -- Incluimos el resto de la instrucción en una solo linea
              + @columnas + ' from ##SUSCRIPTIONUPLOADDELIVERTEMP order by CARTERA desc, ESTADO asc';

--Agregamos la consulta a la instrucción bcp
SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @query + ' queryout D:\BCP\MiArchivo.csv -t; -c -T';

--Ejecutamos el bcp
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;

GO
```

Sin embargo, es probable que tengas que cambiar los parámetros usados por bcp, asignar el procedimiento adecuado que genera la consulta a exportar, generar el nombre correcto del archivo, permitir la execución de xp_cmdshell (que está desactivada por default).

Para consultar todos los parámetros de bcp para asignar las opciones deseadas, revisa [la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#T).

Comment: Tu respuesta es la más próxima a lo que necesito, ahora si con el **-t** lo vuelve con separador de comas, como podría ponerlo con el separador de punto y coma? " ; " y si para agregar la cabecera tengo que hacer algún join en especial

Comment: Cambia `-t,` por `-t;`. El parámetro -t indica cual será el separador. De hecho, edité todo el código para que tengas un ejemplo más completo.

Comment: Probare y modificare lo necesario, muchas gracias por la ayuda.